# Devise 3.2, Confirmation without Login, and Password Creation for New Accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-confirmable

I've upgraded to Devise 3.2.1 and Rails 4.0, and I'm trying to figure out my signup now that one doesn't login on confirmation.

I allow users to create a message and specify the recipient of the message via an email address. Then I send emails notifying the recipient that they've received a message on the service. If the recipient doesn't have an account on the service, I create the account without a password, and the email I send to the recipient acts a confirmation email. With prior versions, the recipient would then click on the link, thus confirming, and then be taken to a password creation stage and then finally, they'd have a confirmed account created with password and can go see the message.

With Devise 3.1, they no longer allow login via confirmation as they consider it a security risk, however I fear it may greatly increase the complexity of my sign up process. I can no longer redirect to a password creation page as they aren't logged in. I'm toying with the idea of taking them to a special signup page or creating the account and then sending a special form of password reset.

I don't want to notify them via email, then send them a second email as a confirmation. That adds unnecessary complexity to my signup.

I wondered if anyone else has dealt with this issue and how they handled it. I'd like to avoid using:

```
config.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation = true
```

as that will go away soon and is really not the right way.

Is there a secure, yet fast way to do this with Devise 3.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm switching to using sorcery ( https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery ) for greater control over authentication and building my flow with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely the problem that [devise invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) gem solves in a secure manner. I would recommend using this tool, rather than trying to hand-roll your own solution which is more likely to contain security flaws.

The gem workflow is basically:

- An admin invites a new user.
- The new user is created with a random password. (I actually [helped](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/commit/3d6cf41c6692ba5d244a70be328986d4ab70b2e7) write this bit!)
- The user is sent an invitation email. (This is fully customisable in how it works, but has some simple default settings.)
- The user receives a link, which contains a URL with a unique `invitation_token`.
- After clicking this link, the user must choose their real password.